# how to make method calls of multiple objects of same class in different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm noob in c++ and have a class (mystack), there's a method (push) in it which can be called using

```
mystack a;
a.push();
```

Now I have created multiple instances of class A and for each of them I want to call the push method, I'm wondering how can I call them in different threads, thanks.

---

Edit

The full code is below (it's long but quite simple and straightforward), there are two instances of class mystack, each of them make a sequence of method calls, I want to make method calls of different instance in different threads, so I want to make push and pop operations of instance stc in a thread and the same operations in stc2 in another thread, how would I achieve this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

//static recursive_mutex mtx;

struct mystack
{
    int *p;
    unsigned int limit, counter;

public:
    unsigned int max()
    {
        return limit;
    }

    ~mystack()
    {
        delete p;
    }

    mystack(int k) : limit(k), p(0), counter(0)
    {
        if (limit > 0)
        {
            p = new int[limit];
        }
    }

    void push(unsigned int k)
    {
        if (counter >= limit)
        {
            throw 1;
        }

        p[counter] = k;
        counter++;
    }

    int pop()
    {
        if (counter <= 0)
        {
            throw 1;
        }

        counter--;

        return p[counter];
    }
};

int main(int, char*[])
{
    mystack stc(5);
    try
    {
        stc.push(1);
        stc.push(2);
        stc.push(3);
        stc.push(4);
        stc.push(5);
        stc.push(6);
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
        try
        {
            cout << "pop out the values" << endl;
            while (true)
            {
                cout << stc.pop() << " ";
            }
        }
        catch (int j)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "stack is now empty" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


    mystack stc2(3);
    try
    {
        stc2.push(1);
        stc2.push(2);
        stc2.push(3);
        stc2.push(4);
        stc2.push(5);
        stc2.push(6);
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
        try
        {
            cout << "pop out the values" << endl;
            while (true)
            {
                cout << stc2.pop() << " ";
            }
        }
        catch (int j)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "stack is now empty" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked a pretty general question, but assuming you don't have any threads that have been created yet, using C++11 and std::thread would be your best bet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct A
{
    int id;
    A(int i) : id(i) {}

    void push() {
        std::cout << id << " pushin." << std::endl;
    }
};

A obj_a(0);
void push_global() {obj_a.push();}

void push_an_A(A& obj) {obj.push();}

int main()
{
    A obj_b(1),
      obj_c(2);

    // globals (not recommended)
    std::thread thread_a(push_global);

    // using lambdas
    auto push_b = [&obj_b](){
        obj_b.push();
    };

    std::thread thread_b(push_b);

    // binding
    std::thread thread_c(std::bind(push_an_A, obj_c));

    thread_a.join();
    thread_b.join();
    thread_c.join();
}
```

Remember to use your compiler's equivalent of `-std=c++11` and `-pthread` options.

**Edit:** For your updated code, (despite the odd use of exceptions as flow control going on there) it's as simple as taking the sequence of operations you're doing and sticking them in a function:

```
void do_sequence(mystack &stack)
{
    try
    {
        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(2);
        stack.push(3);
        stack.push(4);
        stack.push(5);
        stack.push(6);
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
        try
        {
            cout << "pop out the values" << endl;
            while (true)
            {
                cout << stack.pop() << " ";
            }
        }
        catch (int j)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "stack is now empty" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    mystack stc(5),
        stc2(3);

    // note that we need to use std::ref() so that the arguments are correctly
    // passed by reference, otherwise we get memory corruption
    std::thread thread_stc(std::bind(do_sequence, std::ref(stc))),
        thread_stc2(std::bind(do_sequence, std::ref(stc2)));

    thread_stc.join();
    thread_stc2.join();

    return 0;
}
```